# Paperclip + S3 + CloudFront Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

Recently I updated some settings on my application in order to use CloudFront as my official CDN.

While CSS and JS don't give me much trouble, since Rails Asset Pipeline adds a fingerprint to the file, I can't talk the same about images.

Even though Paperclip adds a query string to the images, after update it I'm not seeing the new version, already tried multiple configurations for Cloud Front like:

- Min TTL: 0
- Max TTL: 120
- Default TTL: 60
- Query String Forwarding and Caching: Forward All, cache based on all

But the results are still pretty bad, I can't get my old file:

https://d1bfllp5zjnl7u.cloudfront.net/anuncio_covers/10171/large.jpg?1485379619

becomes the new one:

http://musicjungle.s3.amazonaws.com/anuncio_covers/10171/large.jpg?1485379619

Comment: Did you configure CloudFront to forward the query string to the origin, in Cache Behavior configuration?  If it's not forwarded, it's ignored.

Comment: as described, yes.

Comment: As described, indeed.  My apoligies, I'm not sure how I overlooked that. That is correct. Both of those links are returning the same image for me, which I assume is what you expect.  Is that not what you see?